# Regex: named groups(redirection using .htaccess file)

Tags: regex, .htaccess

How will I redirect to a page when I have to pass two or more variables through `GET` method?

For example:

If I want to redirect `www.abc.com/category/12345-abcdef/` to `www.abc.com?id=12345&name=abcdef`
using `.htaccess` file, how will I do it?

Here `id` would always be a 5 digit integer and `name` can be anything. In fact, I don't need help regarding regex pattern. Just wanna know the syntax when two or more variables are passed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^category/([^-]+)-([^/]+)/?$ /?id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks, @anubhava. Its always good to hear from indians. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: My pleasure if it can be of any help to you.

Comment: It did. Will accept your answer when the time limit is done. Thanks, once again. :)

Comment: I have another question. Kindly comment here when you are online.

Comment: @NavneetSaini: I am online now.

Comment: How can I hide one of the `GET` parameters from the URL using `.htaccess`?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17566342/is-it-possible-to-hide-one-of-the-get-variables-through-htaccess-redirect

Comment: Ok let me try to address that question there.