# Is it possible to hide one of the GET variables through .htaccess redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Suppose I am passing 4 variables through get method, say `game_name`, `game_id`, `game_category`, `game_player`.

the default link would look something like this:
`www.games.com/gameinfo?game_name=zxcvb&game_id=12345&game_category=foo&game_player=bar`

Now, I want to rewrite the URL like:
`www.abc.com/gameinfo/foo/zxcvb/bar`

I do not want to show the id of the game in the link but still want to get it passed using `GET` method.

How can this be done?

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what URL rewriting is about. For examples and code, refer to one of the numerous duplicates

Comment: @Pekka웃, I tried to follow the other questions here but found myself unable to grab it. Could you please explain? PLEASE.

Comment: If id is not present in the URL how do you want to pass it to your backend? Can game_name be used to do a reverse lookup of id?

Comment: @anubhava See, I have a list of links basically. Each link would send a particular `id` to the destination page and then that page will retrieve info from the database b matching that `id` to some field in the database. Now, is it possible to hide this `id`. When the user clicks on a particular link, can ID be sent behind the scenes?

Comment: @anubhava please comment when you are online.

Comment: On your question: `can ID be sent behind the scenes?` It has to come from where. Why are you even trying to hide it? Look at the SO URL where every question has id and title.

Comment: Well Yeah, ok. Fine. I  won't hide it. Thanks again @anubhava

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# From: /gameinfo/12345/foo/zxcvb/bar
# To: /gameinfo?game_name=zxcvb&game_id=12345&game_category=foo&game_player=bar

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(gameinfo)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1?game_name=$2&game_id=$3&game_category=$4&game_player=$5 [L,QSA,NC]
```